# Change WooCommerce default currency based on user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change the default currency in WooCommerce based on user roles in WordPress.

For the user role named "customer", the default price needs to be in SEK and for all others the price must be in DKK

I've tried a lot of different solutions but can't seem to find one that is working.

```
global $current_user;
 if (in_array('customer', $current_user->roles)) {

Don't know what to put here.. :D

 }
```

Right now i have no way of moving forward, can't seem to find anything on Google or StackOverflow which helps my situation.

I can't find a function that can change default currency programmaticly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `woocommerce_currency` filter

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency', 'set_role_currency', 200);
function set_role_currency($currency){
 global $current_user;
 if (in_array('customer', $current_user->roles)) { return 'SEK'; }
return $currency; //this will return your woocommerce default currency
}
```

Comment: Hi shir,

Thank you a lot for your suggestion.

Based on the code it should work, but all the prices are still in DKK when logged in as customer, which i find a bit weird.

I've placed it at the bottom of my functions.php

But result is not as expected.

Comment: the global $current_user is wrong I think.
Try this instead:
$user = get_current_user();
    if (in_array('customer', $user->roles))...

Comment: Thanks for another try :-D

Hm, still same outcome. Still comes out in DKK. Which is weird.

Comment: Try to clear the function, and just add return 'SEK';  Let's check that this filter is being called

Comment: Sorry Shir, your code was actually working. I had a plugin that was clinching.

Thank you for your assistance :-)!

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check below code.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency','ji_woocommerce_currency',10);
function ji_woocommerce_currency( $currency ){     
$user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
if ( $user_info->roles[0]=="administrator" ) { 
    return 'USD'; 
} elseif ( $user_info->roles[0]=="subscriber" ) { 
    return 'GBP'; 
} else {
    return 'EUR';
}
```

}